# Handle events for paused azure function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-trigger

Will azure function handle missed events after pause? I expect nothing bad if we use queue as input binding, possible everything will be good for event grid, because we need to configure topic, which should act as a queue. What about BlobTrigger binding? If new file was added during function pause, will it fire function after it's start?

```
public async Task Run([BlobTrigger("path/to/blob/{name}", Connection = "Conn")] byte[] blobData, string blobTrigger)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Blob Trigger internally [polls the logs and containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp#polling-and-latency) for new or updated blobs, and [maintains receipts](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp#blob-receipts) for processed blobs. This ensures blobs are processed as expected and pausing a function app should not affect this.